# how to receive data from server to android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an Android application about cars tracking using GPS.

Like this "the system is having GPS and send a data (Longitude and Latitude) to Web Server GPS, and then Web Server will send it (Latitude and Longitude) to client (android)"

My question is how the client (android) to receive packet data from server that include (longitude and latitude) to display position car in google maps (android).

Comment: You can create web service to get data from server

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a web service that returns the data you need, and poll it at regular intervals. This is the easier solution.

A better one would be to use push notifications by utilizing Google's C2DM, but it's still in beta as far as I know (which is a shame, truly...). But still, it might be good enough for your needs, check it out [here](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use web service which serves location of cars or use http.

Comment: i have my own server to receive data, i need step by step to receive packet data from server  ??